# What are the connotations of "getting wet"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Do you understand it by its sexual or literal (and serious) meaning? I'm trying to compose a sentence like this:

Are you getting wet later? (with a picture of pool attached)

As a non-native English speaker, I wonder what your first impression will be.

Comment: It's not an established idiom, other than to mean "coat with water".  (And perhaps localized meanings among young people.)

Comment: This all depends on context.

Comment: I suppose the intended meaning is "Will you swim later?" The "attached picture" steers the meaning, though. The choice of verb tense is slightly "foreign" to my native English ear.

Comment: If you want to avoid the sexual connotation, just ask " Are you going swimming later?" If you want a potential for ambiguity, keep it how it is.

Comment: This is very non-idiomatic. That is, it is not what a native speaker would naturally say, even though it might be strictly following grammatical rules. In other words, it sounds weird.

Comment: @Skooba I think it's very ineffective as a double-entredre, for the reasons Mitch stated: it sounds weird.

Comment: @DanBron I think that why for me it brings up double-entredre... it sounds weird, begging the question *even if with a picture of a pool, are you talking about going swimming?* Maybe I'm just a young horn dog though....

Comment: "Getting wet" can mean a lot of things in slang.  It can mean becoming sexually aroused (of a woman), but it can also mean getting drunk or drinking, and in US black culture it can mean murdering someone.  Of these three senses, the sexual one is possibly the least likely to be phrased "Are you getting wet *later*?" That would be like asking a man "Are you getting hard later?" except that the latter has no natural literal meaning to distract from the innuendo.

Comment: All of which is to say that most readers probably would not assume a sexual meaning if they saw "are you getting wet later?"

Comment: @Skooba Double entendres, by construction are supposed to be *legitimately* readable and interpretable for either meaning. That’s where their power comes from: the ability to say insinuate something while using behind a mask of perfect plausible deniability. If one interpretation isn’t available (eg due to weirdness / grammatical awkwardness), the whole thing breaks down. No, this sentence doesn’t work, for any use. It’s non-idiomatic nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am only familiar with the beach communities in the Northeast United States **"Are you getting wet later?",** **"I'm going to go get wet," "She's going down to get wet,"** are very common idioms. Perhaps because not everyone actually "swims" in the ocean.

While a captioned picture of a pool would probably evoke a double-entendre, a photo of the same conversation at the seashore would be less ambiguous. (At least, to a native Yankee.)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the wording *is* idiomatic, at least in one dialect  of English.

Comment: That's amazing. Regionalisms are so surprising sometimes!

Comment: True, 'getting wet' in England often refers to going out in the rain.

Comment: Well that's a new one to me...I've heard of "taking a dip"and "going for a swim".